# What is wrong with this bash scripting syntax for adding an element to an array?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, scripting, sh

A simple shell script used for creating some system reporting contains the code

```
ARRAY=$(awk -F ':' '$3>=1000 && $3<60000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
ARRAY+=('root')
```

The array's declaration in the first line doesn't produce any error output, but for the second line I get an error message saying: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: What is your `bash` version? The first line does not mean you are working with an array, `$(..)` is a command substitution syntax. Either way it should not produce the error you said

Comment: Use: `ARRAY=($(awk -F ':' '$3>=1000 && $3<60000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd))`

Comment: Éxactly, it should work like Cyrus wrote. However, I then get this error for the initial array initialization: Syntax error: "(" unexpected - And if I leave out the outer brackets (s. above), the array gets initialized, but then the second line produces this totally obscure error. My bash version is 4.3.30.

Comment: I demonstrated this odd behavior and took a screenshot of it, which you can view here: [Weird bash behavior](https://pasteboard.co/YQMZJ2mP.png)

Comment: Important: `sh` is not `bash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem, from your screenshot, is that you are not running it as a bash script.  You're doing `sh testscript` which executes it with the `sh` shell, which is not `bash`.  Make the changes that @Cyrus recommended and either make the script executable so you use the shebang line and do `./testscript` or use bash to run it `bash testscript`

Also, `set +x` turns off tracing/debugging so when you're hitting unexpected problems you'd be better using `set -x` to turn it on for the block in question.

I demonstrated the problem for myself as follows:

```
$ cat testscript
ARRAY=$(awk -F ':' '$3>=1000 && $3<60000 {print $1}' /etc/passwd)
ARRAY+=('root')
$ sh testscript
testscript: 2: testscript: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")"
$ bash testscript
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it now indeed behaves in the way I would have expected it to behave. Still I really wonder why `sh` (after having initialized the array successfully with the right values when leaving out the outer brackets)  produces this (to me) totally weird syntax error for `ARRAY+=('root')` - Why does it expect a closing bracket in this line, although there already is an opening and a closing bracket?

Comment: @c128linux It seems to be treating the line as though it's doing `name()` to define a function, in this case it would be named `ARRAY+=`.  There's an unexpected word in the middle of the parens though.  If you take `'root'` out it will then complain about an illegal function name

Comment: Thanks for this in-depth explanation! @Cyrus Answer accepted ;)